Determining when a time series switches which of two Gaussians it samples from
I'm sampling from what should be an elliptical 2D Gaussian. However, one of the instruments in the setup seems to be switching between two values for the phase between synthesizers, which results in two 2D Gaussians showing up. 
I can see this behavior in a time series, most obviously if I look at the absolute value of the Q series. 
What I want to do now is determine where we're switching from one Gaussian to the other, and analyze each of these segments where I'm in one particular Guassian separately. So instead of one time series in this plot, I'd have 5 time series, plus two small fractional time series.
But this has turned out to be pretty difficult. My first thought was to determine the envelope and then fit to a square wave. I tried a Hilbert transform but it just looked like noise; low- and high- pass filtering the data before applying the transform, but neither made it look more like a square wave; a rolling maximum looks somewhat more like a square wave but I can't get a good fit since it's still pretty noisy; a few minutes spent in python's ruptures makes me think it's too general-purpose, and it's picking out a lot of random noise spikes as transitions.
So I have a pretty good understanding of the states that are giving me this data, but I don't know how I can actually do the analysis. Anyone able to give me some pointers? The Q data I'm working on can be downloaded from here.
EDIT: If I do a 100 point rolling maximum and low pass filter that I can get a decent fit to a square wave. But it requires a good bit of manual tweaking, and I want something that will run reliably with no supervision.
